# creating new table by conditioning on columns of existing table

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, case

I am a new sql learner. I am stuck with the following problem:

Suppose I have the following table :

| ID | detail |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | 11 |
| A1 | 12 |
| A1 | null |
| A1 | 0 |
| A2 | 11 |
| A2 | 13 |

Now I want to create a new table with two columns ID and result (say), where each ID appears once. If any row corresponding to an ID has 12 in the detail column, then result = 1, else 0. So basically my result should be the following table:

| ID | detail |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | 1 |
| A2 | 0 |

My attempt to solve this was:

```
insert into new_table select ID, (select detail,
                                     (case
                                        when detail = 12 then '0'
                                        else '1'
                                      end) as new_column from table) 
from table;
```

But this piece of code is giving me error : operand should contain 1 column. I do not know how to approach this problem. Please help me understand how to solve this. I am trying this in MySql.

Comment: Please update your post with the error you are getting, and add the approriate dbms tag.

Comment: a subselect can only return a scalr value and not 2 columns

Answer (score 2):

Use a CTAS statement for the creating the table, and use a case expression with aggregation.

```
create table table2 as (
  select id, 
   max(case when detail = 12 then 1 else 0 end) as detail
  from table1
  group by id
  );
```

| id | detail |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | 1 |
| A2 | 0 |

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a subquery. You can make the expression directly in the select-list.

Use GROUP BY to make the result have one row per value of ID.

```
INSERT INTO new_table 
SELECT ID, MAX(CASE detail WHEN 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM old_table
GROUP BY ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

`EXISTS` will return only the correct scalar value and it will be fast

```
CREATE TABLE old_table
    (`ID` varchar(2), `detail` varchar(4))
;
    
INSERT INTO old_table
    (`ID`, `detail`)
VALUES
    ('A1', '11'),
    ('A1', '12'),
    ('A1', NULL),
    ('A1', '0'),
    ('A2', '11'),
    ('A2', '13')
;
```

> ```
> Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
    (`ID` varchar(2), `detail` varchar(4))
;
```

```
INSERT INTO new_table
SELECT DISTINCT ID, (EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM old_table o2 WHERE o2.`detail` = 12 AND o2.ID = o1.ID))
FROM old_table o1
```

> ```
> Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT* FROM new_table
```

| ID | detail |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | 1 |
| A2 | 0 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iniMKIwx)